# Safari: Can I open all bookmarks in a bookmark folder in a new window?

Tags: macos, safari, bookmarks

Is it possible to open all bookmarks in a bookmark folder in Safari in a **new** Safari window?

I know that I can do this with a single bookmark, but can I do the same with a bookmark folder?

Answer (score 3):

Open the Bookmarks menu, top left, right click the folder of bookmarks, Open in Tabs...

[image]

Though irritatingly, it re-uses the current window, so maybe start with a new one first.

Comment: Yes - but this opens the tabs in the *actual* window - I would like them to open in a *new* window.

Comment: Instant notifications of changes are a curse..... But this extra step inexactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score -3):

Option click folder in Favorites.

Comment: on Bookmark bar

Answer (score -3):

use Bookmarks->Show BookMarks from the Safari menu. This will open all the list of bookmarks on your left side. There you can rearrange or edit the bookmarks.

Comment: How does this help OP "open all bookmarks in a bookmark folder in Safari in a new Safari window"?